# How to find exponent coefficients in a sum of exponents?

Tags: problem-solving, exponential-function

It is easy to determine a coefficient 'c' of exp(c*x), just log it and find slope. Or if it's

exp(c1*x) + exp(c2*x)

then after log from 0 to the right of left we would find 'c1' and 'c2'. But what if we have more terms? For example, such a sum

exp(x) + exp(1.5*x) + exp(2.5*x) + exp(3*x)

if you loged it, almost would have no difference between
exp(x) + exp(3*x)
So, please, how could I find them in another way?

[image]

Comment: http://i41.tinypic.com/fep8up.png
Illustration

Comment: Although the description is slightly vague (what form are you given the function in, if you don't know the coefficients?), you might succeed by finding the largest term (which will dominate all the others) and subtract it from the function given, repeating the process until you arrive at a single exponential. In your case, you'd find the $\exp(3x)$ term, subtract it from the function given and repeat the process to find the second-largest one, ..

Comment: Not sure that this will help you but notice that :

- the derivative at $0$ will give you the sum of coefficients. 
- the second derivative at $0$ the sum of square of coefficients and so on.
(an appropriate answer would require to know what information is available or could be made available to you...).
Another idea is to remove the largest exponential term and study the remaining part and so on...

Comment: Oups the last part was proposed earlier by Peter (sorry...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know, that 
$$y(x) = \exp(c_1 x)+\exp(c_2 x)+\cdots+\exp(c_n x),$$
then
calculate $y(1), y(2), \ldots, y(n)\;$: $\;p_1 = y(1), p_2 = y(2), \ldots, p_n=y(n)$.
You'll get system of equations:

$$\left\{
\begin{array}{r}
\exp(c_1)+\exp(c_2)+\cdots+\exp(c_n)=p_1; \\
\exp(2c_1)+\exp(2c_2)+\cdots+\exp(2c_n)=p_2; \\
\cdots \cdots \cdots \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \\
\exp(nc_1)+\exp(nc_2)+\cdots+\exp(nc_n)=p_n.
\end{array}
\right.
$$

If denote $s_1=\exp(c_1), s_2=\exp(c_2), \ldots, s_n=\exp(c_n)$, then 
$$\left\{
\begin{array}{r}
s_1+s_2+\cdots+s_n=p_1; \\
s_1^2+s_2^2+\cdots+s_n^2=p_2; \\
\cdots \cdots \cdots \qquad \qquad \\
s_1^n+s_2^n+\cdots+s_n^n=p_n.
\end{array}
\right.
$$

With the help of [Power sum symmetric polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_sum_symmetric_polynomial)
 you'll find values $e_1,e_2, \ldots, e_n$ $-$ elementary symmetric polynomials:

$$\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
e_1 = s_1+s_2+\cdots+s_n = p_1; \\
e_2 = s_1s_2+s_1s_3+\cdots+s_{n-1}s_n = \dfrac{1}{2}(p_1^2-p_2); \\
\cdots \cdots \cdots\qquad \qquad \\
e_n = s_1s_2\cdots s_n=\dfrac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{j=1}^n (-1)^{j-1}e_{n-j}p_j;
\end{array}
\right.
$$

so $s_1,s_2,\ldots,s_n$ are roots of  equation

$$s^n-e_1\cdot s^{n-1}+\cdots+(-1)^{n-1}e_{n-1}\cdot s+(-1)^n e_n=0.$$

Finally, when you will find roots $s_1,s_2,\ldots,s_n$,

$$c_j=\ln(s_j), \; j=1,\ldots,n.$$

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends much of the control you have over the studied function.

You may apply an integral transform to your function (with the advantage of additionnal constants in front of the exponentials possible) :

- Laplace transform for example : $e^{7\,x}+3\;e^{11\,x}\mapsto \frac 1{s-7}+\frac 3{s-11} $ see this [Alpha result](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=laplace%20transform%20exp%287%2at%29%2b3%2aexp%2811%2at%29)
- Fourier transform (multiplying $x$ by $-i$ first) to get for example : $e^{-5\,i\,x}+e^{-11\,xi\,}\mapsto \sqrt{2\pi}[\delta(\omega-5)+\delta(\omega-11)]$ with $\delta$ the [Dirac distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function).
  [Alpha result](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=fourier%20transform%20exp%28-5%2aI%2at%29%2bexp%28-11%2aI%2at%29).
- wavelet transform and so on...

Another method is to use :

- the derivative at $0$ that will give you the sum of coefficients.
- the second derivative at 0 the sum of square of coefficients and so on.

You could too (as suggested by Peter Košinár) evaluate the largest exponential, subtract it from your function, estimate the next largest exponential and so on...